# Attaching Sent Email to Case

Tags: case, email2case

I am using Process builder to Send email to list of members. Once the email sent to members,i want to create a case and want to track that email sent to these people.
After that when the member replies,it should not create the new case.it should tag to the same case and update the email content to that case.

Basically,i want to track the emails sent and received with content.How i can achieve this.

Any suggestion...

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am not really sure why are you using the process builder for this.

Declarative, you might achieve this functionality by using Email-to-Case mechanism.